# How to conver list array to object?

Tags: javascript

How to convert array as below to object like output below?

```
const list = [
  { id: 1, data: { name: 'John', age: 25 } },
  { id: 2, data: { name: 'Jane', age: 22 } },
  { id: 3, data: { name: 'Tom', age: 20 } }
]
```

output:

```
{
  1: { id: 1, name: 'John', age: 25 },
  2: { id: 2, name: 'Jane', age: 22 },
  3: { id: 3, name: 'Tom', age: 20 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far and what error you get on your triage?

Answer (score 2):

You can use array reduce method. Inside the callback method add the key in the accumulator object represented by `acc` in the below code

```js
const list = [{
    id: 1,
    data: {
      name: 'John',
      age: 25
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    data: {
      name: 'Jane',
      age: 22
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    data: {
      name: 'Tom',
      age: 20
    }
  }
]

const newData = list.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.id] = { ...curr.data,
    id: curr.id
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(newData)
```